# How come CheckObject.checked won't work?

Tags: javascript, input, checkbox, click

I have a checkbox that by default is set to checked:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkobj" checked />
```

And I use the following javascript to uncheck it depending on the value of a variable:

```
var chk = document.getElementById("chkobj");

if(myStr=="1")
{
      chk.checked=true;
}
else
{
      chk.checked=false;
}
```

Yet, no matter what I try, the value won't change. Any idea why? I rather stick to pure JS than use jQuery. I'm really curious as to why this won't just work in plain JS. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where is the value of `myStr` being set? Can you post the related code?

Comment: The value of what wont change?

Comment: Does this script execute before the html tag? is it inside onload?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the element itself. Even if you set chk.checked = false. Which makes chk.checked==false to be true. The element would still have checked attribute and would probably display as a checked box... try chk.removeAttribute('checked') as well to remove the check. And chk.setAttribute('checked', 'checked') to check the box visually.

Comment: On the other hand.. like the comments above.. checkout when your script is actually executed...